# parsing json string using json parse method

Tags: javascript, json

Hi friends I have a I have a json string as shown below. How to parse the string to get day,min_amount,max_amount values .

```
[{"day":"1970-01-01","min_amount":"0.00","max_amount":"0.00"},{"day":"1970-01-02","min_amount":"1.00","max_amount":"2.00"}]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Just use JSON.parse. The syntax for accessing a value is simple:

```
obj = JSON.parse(json)
day = obj[0].day
min_amount = obj[0].day
max_amount = obj[0].day
```

The great thing about Javascript is how simple it is to use JSON, because JSON is just a serialized version of plain-old javascript hashes, arrays, and scalars.

Answer (score 0):

It's already in object form. SO use this :

```
var x = [{"day":"1970-01-01","min_amount":"0.00","max_amount":"0.00"},{"day":"1970-01-02","min_amount":"1.00","max_amount":"2.00"}]
jQuery.each(x,function(e){
    console.log(x[e])
     console.log(x[e].day)
});
```

Here is the working example : http://jsfiddle.net/u6J8A/

Answer (score 0):

As you may not have noticed, JSON is JavaScript synthax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [
        {"day":"1970-01-01","min_amount":"0.00","max_amount":"0.00"},
        {"day":"1970-01-02","min_amount":"1.00","max_amount":"2.00"}
    ];
</script>
```

Dumping it directly in the JavaScript code is perfectly valid.

But if you are fetching this data at run time and have the information as a string, you can convert it using `JSON.parse(string)`.

The information can be then read from this structure by the variables `data[0].day`,  `data[0].min_amount`,  `data[0].max_amount`, `data[1].day`,  `data[1].min_amount`,  `data[1].max_amount`.